# How to clear background processes in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am working on a ram booster app and I need help with the code to clear inactive and background processes in android ?

I have tried this code but didn't make the job

```
public void freeMemory(){
     System.runFinalization();
     Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
     System.gc();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

for (RunningAppProcessInfo pid : am.getRunningAppProcesses()) {
    am.killBackgroundProcesses(pid.processName);
}
```

You will be needing this permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
```

[This](https://github.com/todoroo/astrid) is a open source task management application that could help you.

Comment: You should try it and report although i am pretty sure it will work